# How does one add a directory to a web host through code?

Tags: php, sql-server, directory

I am working on a web application on a web host server. The server is an Apache server running MySQL and I am using PHP. My server is on 000webost.com . I am trying to code so that a new directory is added to the server every time a new test is created in my application. How would I do this?

Comment: `mkdir()`? Not sure what your question is.

Comment: maybe, I am new to all this stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a new directory w/ PHP's `mkdir('mydir', 0777);`

[PHP mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

Comment: ok, so say you create a directory called 'questions1' how would you insert a file into that directory?